# Subclassing Error in Nodejs with babel produces error

Tags: node.js, babeljs

```
'use strict';

export default class UnknownEntityError extends Error {
    constructor() {
        super(message);
}
```

produces:

> 'this' is not allowed before super() (This is an error on an internal node. Probably an internal error)

Searching on google produces some links that lead to a 404. But when I check the cache I can see this is a [known issue](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:BeE6tfJolBsJ:https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2971%20&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us). What I don't see is the resolution

```
node -v
v5.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The Babel issue tracker was moved, fixing dead links is still a TODO. This is a current Babel bug being tracked in https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T2694.

I have a PR open with a fix: https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/3096